# How can I compare multiple mutual funds on a single chart at once?

Tags: stocks, investing, mutual-funds, google-finance, chart

Google finance (finance.google.com, or [www.google.com/finance](http://www.google.com/finance)), used to have the ability to compare many stocks or mutual funds (tickers) at once. Now, apparently after they significantly altered and downgraded the site in 2018, I can't seem to compare more than 2 at a time on a chart (see example below). **Does anyone know how I can compare multiple tickers at once again on a chart? I found that feature REALLY useful when making long-term investment decisions and I don't know how I can get the same information and visual comparison anymore.**

Note: Morningstar seems to have the same limitation.

[image: Example comparison of two]
([Source](https://www.google.com/search?sa=X&tbm=fin&q=INDEXRUSSELL:+RUT&stick=H4sIAAAAAAAAAONgecRowi3w8sc9YSntSWtOXmNU5eIKzsgvd80rySypFBLnYoOyeKW4uTj1c_UNTKrK0sp5AHTxG5U5AAAA&ved=0ahUKEwj3s6im18HaAhXhj1QKHWYUD3wQ0uIBCK0BMBE&biw=1869&bih=965#scso=uid_vxrWWtrOHoiU0gKQx534BA_5:0&smids=/m/0cqyw&wptab=COMPARE) --> then click the "5 years" comparison button. Note that if you type a new ticker into the "Compare custom stock or index" box it will *replace* one of the current comparisons [which is what I DON'T want] rather than *add* the new ticker to the current comparison [which is what I DO want])

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thanks, [Bob Baerker for getting me on the right track](https://money.stackexchange.com/a/94406/71271)! I'd like to post my own answer.

(This works for stocks or mutual funds--doesn't really matter).

1. Go to [www.marketwatch.com](https://www.marketwatch.com/)
2. In the top right, click "SEARCH"
3. Enter a symbol/ticker. Ex: "APPL" (Apple), then click the top result, as shown below:

   - [image]
4. Once it opens, click the "Advanced Charting" button near the middle of the screen.

   - [image]
5. Now, near the middle of the screen, click the box that says "COMPARE SYMBOL" and enter another symbol, ex: "AMZN" (Amazon), then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

   - [image]
6. Repeat adding more symbols as desired. Ex: "GOOG" (Google), "MCHP" (Microchip), "USSPX" (USAA S&P 500 Index mutual fund).
7. When done adding all of the symbols (stocks, mutual funds) you want, click any other options you want, ex: "5Y" to look at the last 5 years.
8. Now you can hover your mouse over the chart to see the exact values at any given moment. Here's a screenshot showing the above 4 stocks and 1 mutual fund plotted all at once for the last 5 years, including a mouse-over view of the exact values on 11/01/2015.

   - [image]

This is a really great tool and nicely replaces the old Google Finance tool that was very similar but not quite as detailed.

It also contains more advanced plotting features at the bottom such as the MACD ([Moving Average Convergence Divergence](https://www.google.com/search?q=macd&rlz=1C1CHFX_enUS602US602&oq=macd&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j69i60l3.659j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)), which is essentially just a low-pass filter of the data so you can see the more local trends.

Though I don't yet understand all the intricacies of this chart it certainly does have a lot of features and looks super useful!

**If you'd like a jump-start on your charting adventures, use this link here to jump straight to the "AAPL" chart page where you can begin adding your own stock and mutual fund symbols to compare: https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/aapl/charts.**

Comment: I just want to say this answer of mine still works and I've been referencing it regularly for years, each time I want to track my investments, buy or sell something, or choose a new mutual fund.

Comment: Here I am again referring to my own answer.

Answer (score 5):

BigCharts will graph up to 10 symbols at once.

http://bigcharts.marketwatch.com/

Enter a symbol  and select "Advanced Chart"

Click on "Compare To"

Enter other symbols and Voila! , you have multiple pretty colored graphs.

You can select various types of charts as well as different time periods.

Comment: Although it does work, this service could be much better. Before Google ruined what they offer by replacing it with their new garbage it was so much more user-friendly than bigcharts. +1 though. Thanks for pointing this option out!

Comment: I subscribe to Thompson Reuters for EOD data and I have software for charting that data so now I'm only superficially familiar with BigCharts and StockCharts.  Google: "multiple stock charts single page" and start exploring other possibilities.

Answer (score -2):

While this may not exactly answer the question, you should think twice. Why do you want to compare past performance? I'm far more interested in future performance, and the only surefire predictor of future performance is low expenses.

It's the expenses and the diversification you should be looking at! Past returns are past. Somebody else has obtained the returns already. Move on, and focus on future returns.